# What is CDI @Dependant default scope?

Tags: servlets, cdi

1. What is Java CDI `@Dependant` default scope?
2. What is a scope of `@Dependant` CDI bean when it is injected into
   `@WebServlet`?
3. What is CDI scope of java `@WebServlet`?

Answer (score 1):

I will try to briefly answer with link to CDI spec as that is the ultimate source for most of your questions.

> What is java CDI @Dependant default scope?

[CDI spec has a whole chapter dedicated to this](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0/cdi-spec.html#dependent_context), you should take a look.
It is classified as a CDI scope yet has different behaviour in a way that new instance is created for every injection point.

> What is a scope of @Dependant CDI bean when it is injected into @WebServlet?

I suppose you are asking about the lifecycle of such a bean.Dependent beans have their lifecycle tied to the lifecycle of a bean they were injected into. E.g. dependent bean will "exist" as long as does the bean you injected it into.

Now, `WebServlet` itself isn't a pure bean but rather an 'injection target'. That means a non-contextual object that you just present to CDI and let it resolve all IPs. In which case whoever is responsible for injection is also [responsible for cleanup](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0/cdi-spec.html#dependent_destruction). I would assume the bean lives as long as `WebServlet` does here.

> What is CDI scope of java @WebServlet?

Like I hinted before, there is no scope as this isn't a bean but an injection target. It is a (non-contextual) object that is not maintained by CDI (meaning someone else is responsible for creation/destruction) and CDI only allows you to inject into it.

Answer (score 0):

I made appropriate test.

It turned out that attempt to inject @Dependant CDI bean into @WebServlet results in Runtime exception:

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalArgumentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type DefaultScopedBean with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject protected com.example.WithDefaultScopeBeanServlet.bean
  at com.example.WithDefaultScopeBeanServlet.bean(WithDefaultScopeBeanServlet.java:0)
      at org.jboss.weld.manager.InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.createInjectionTarget(InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.java:81)
      at org.jboss.weld.manager.InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.createInjectionTarget(InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.java:69)
```

Actually I was lacking beans.xml file.

When I added it, I could insert @Default CDI bean into servlet, similar like a POJO.